# How can I implement TLS on a connection with very low throughput?

Tags: tls, iot

I'm doing a IoT project therefore want to reduce connection overhead to a minimum. We want to secure the communication, especially the authenticity and confidentiality. With a standard TLS protocol, a 2-way authorization requires certificates to be sent from both sides of the communication. That will result in a huge delay in our application (using Bluetooth as a data link).

The workaround we can think of is instead of sharing certificates at run time, we can pre-share those certificates in two entities. So during TLS establishment, no certificate exchange is required... Seems this is not standard usage supported by TLS.

Is it a good idea to do so? Any other approach?

1. We want to reduce the amount of data transmitted during TLS handshake. The reason behind this is bluetooth datalink is relatively slow... We want to improve the user experience.
2. The whole system is secured based on certificates. Therefore we prefer to stick to TLS with certificate unless TLS-PSK provides a significant performance improvement...(We need to deal with the symmetric keys for TLS-PSK)
3. I notice SPAKE2+ is available recently. What's the difference then if I directly use SPAKE2+ instead of TLS-PSK?

Comment: Have you looked into TLS 1.3 already? It seems to include some features like 0-RTT which could reduce overhead.

Comment: Also the question you should be asking instead is "How can I implement TLS on a connection with very low throughput?"

Comment: When you say _"That will result in huge delay on our application"_ is the problem number of round-trips or the amount of data being sent? For example by pre-sharing the certificate like you are imagining, you are reducing the amount of data to send, but still need the same number of round trips because both sides still need to sign the handshake with the certificate's private key.

Comment: Have you considered the [Pre-Shared Key (PSK) mode in TLS](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4279)?

Comment: This looks more a performance issue, you should monitor your app and see where the issue is, probably you are sending too much data over Bluetooth, but is missing information

Answer (score 6):

Most of the overhead is typically in the TLS handshake (see [TLS explained](https://tls.ulfheim.net/) and [The New Illustrated TLS Connection](https://tls13.ulfheim.net/)). In particular,

- the certificates are often quite large,
- in the certificate non-EC public keys are quite large.

In this regard, you could:

- Use ECDH instead of FFDH (shorter public keys).
- You might want to have support for session resumption in order to avoid sending certificates as much as possible.
- You could use EC key pairs which are smaller than RSA keys (which leads to smaller certificates) but you might be willing to support [deterministic signatures](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6979).
- You might want to avoid using intermediate certificates in order to send a single certificate per direction.
- You could try using raw keys instead of certificates.
- [RFC7924](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7924.html) adds support for caching certificate between TLS handshakes.
- [RFC8879](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8879.html) adds support for compressing certificates using zlib/brotli/zstd.
- You might be interested in the [support](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8902.html) for [ETSI certificates](https://www.etsi.org/deliver/etsi_ts/103000_103099/103097/01.03.01_60/ts_103097v010301p.pdf). I never heard about those but they are supposed to be optimized for bandwidth (?).

Other things:

- You could use TLS v1.3 in order to be able to send data after the first round trip (1RTT).
- In TLS v1.3, you can probably disable the middlebox compatibility mode if you do not use TCP as a transport.
- You might be interested in the [compact TLS (cTLS) draft](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/draft-ietf-tls-ctls/) which is expected to be more compact.
- There is some overhead each time you send a TLS frame (depending on the ciphersuite) (something like 23 bytes for most TLS v1.3 ciphersuites?) so sending application data one byte at a time will lead to a greater overhead: try packing messages instead of sending a lot of very small ones.

See as well [RFC9191](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9191.html) which as several references dealing with the ”long certificate” problem.

Answer (score -1):

Please see the [iotivity open source project](https://github.com/iotivity/iotivity/tree/master/resource/csdk).

Additionally, the regarding open source provides ECDHE_PSK Cipher-suite using certificates via BLE channel so that it may not be bad to go for your previous option.

Comment: Why see that project? How would it help? The documentation is very light, so it's not obvious why one would even consider it for this use case. Are you associated with the project? If so, you need to disclose that fact.